# Why my text is printed on page and soon disappears in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, if-statement

this is my code

---

i was trying to make a signup form and i made a script

---

i jst tried that the username should contain both alphabets and numbers and nothing else

---

if this condition is true than it continues
else it will give an error message displayed jst below it

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <style>
            #sign_up_details {
                padding: 10px;
            }
    </style>
<form name="sign_up_details">
    <h3>Enter your details below</h3>

    <input type="textbox" id="username" placeholder="Enter your desired username" />
    <p id="usrnm_check"></p><br>

    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your desired password" />
    <p id="pass_check"></p><br>

    <input type="textbox" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" />
    <p id="email_check"></p><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="store()" />
</form>

<script>
        var usrnm = document.getElementById("username");
        var pass = document.getElementById("password");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");

        var usrnm_check = document.getElementById("usrnm_check");
        var pass_check = document.getElementById("pass_check");
        var email_check = document.getElementById("email_check");


    function store() {

        var newReg = /^[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+$/

        if (usrnm.value.match(newReg)) {
            //next action here
        } else {
            usrnm_check.innerHTML = "Username should have alphabets and numbers";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

for eg when i keep the username field empty and click on submit the error which is to be displayed comes below it but it soon disappears.
i dont know the reason for it.

Comment: could you update your code in fiddle.

Comment: you will have to use store() with onsubmit

Comment: When you click the `submit` button your javascript is executed, but the browser then submits the form, which reloads the page. Add `return false;` to your `store()` function to prevent the form being submitted.

Comment: Your `regex` should be `/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i`

Answer (score 1):

you will have to set the store in onsubmit event and not on the submit button onclick event because,onclick will execute the function and submit the form as well.

here is fiddle

[execute function before submit](https://jsfiddle.net/4tvo5e76/1/)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <style>
            #sign_up_details {
                padding: 10px;
            }
    </style>
<form name="sign_up_details" onsubmit="return store()">
    <h3>Enter your details below</h3>

    <input type="textbox" id="username" placeholder="Enter your desired username" />
    <p id="usrnm_check"></p><br>

    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your desired password" />
    <p id="pass_check"></p><br>

    <input type="textbox" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" />
    <p id="email_check"></p><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script>
        var usrnm = document.getElementById("username");
        var pass = document.getElementById("password");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");

        var usrnm_check = document.getElementById("usrnm_check");
        var pass_check = document.getElementById("pass_check");
        var email_check = document.getElementById("email_check");


    function store() {

        var newReg = /^[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+$/

        if (usrnm.value.match(newReg)) {
            //next action here
          return true;
        } else {
            usrnm_check.innerHTML = "Username should have alphabets and numbers";
         return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<form action="/dosomething.htm" method="GET" onsubmit="return store(this)">
     [...]
     <input type="submit" value="Go">
   </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function store() {

        var newReg = /^[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+$/

        if (usrnm.value.match(newReg)) {
            //next action here
            return true;
        } else {
            usrnm_check.innerHTML = "Username should have alphabets and numbers";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Notice return true and return false statements in store() and in form onSubmit. If the store() will return false the form will not get submitted. At present your message goes away after display because your form gets submitted even if the validation fails.

Hope this helps!!